# Does a redis server delete expired keys in between commands of a lua script?

Tags: redis

Let's say the key `asd` will expire at some point.
And a client runs this lua script:

```
local a = EXISTS asd
local b = EXISTS asd
```

Is it possible to have `a` as true and `b` as false?
Or should I rest assured that the deletion of expired keys doesn't happen while scripts or MULTI commands are running?

Context: 
I'm creating a kind of a site where queries about other users take long to process. So I thought of creating these queries, storing these in some keys and expire them after x minutes, so that they are regenerated on request.

I have a script that checks if a given query has expired, and regenerates it. Something like this:

```
local e = EXISTS query
if e == "1" then
    -- generate query results
end
-- return results
```

Comment: @RyanVincent yeah, sure, no problem, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Right answer (edited):

No, it is impossible :) Time is frozen during the script's execution.

## Wrong answer:

Yes, it is possible. Expiry is checked/enforced with every access to the key.

Comment: Are you sure this is impossible? I have had a key expire during execution of an lua script when the redis db had maxmemory_policy set to volatile-ttl and the db ran out of memory during script execution.